# Any way to see my personal flag history on chat?

Tags: support, chat, flags

As the question title says, I am wondering if there is any way for an user to review the history of flags he raised on one of the chat sites. The main sites provide a flag-summary page, but I couldn't find a way to access the same information for the chat sites.

Are those simply not available? I have found an [old unanswered feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240076/flagging-history-for-chat-network) asking for a "chat flag history" feature to be made available to mods, but it doesn't really cover the case of an user simply wanting to review the flags it raised.

Before someone ask, I wanted to review the flag history to avoid raising the same flag on questionable content that I already flagged in the past.

Comment: Indeed, simply not available. And there is already pending request to add exactly this. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard To be completely fair, I was asking for an history pages that included ANY kind of flags, not just the moderator-level ones like the feature-request asked. But thanks anyway. Maybe it is worth to add a community wiki answer on this one to make more evident that as now no such feature is available.